# What does 角が立つ mean?

Tags: meaning, particle-に, particle-が

> 智に働けば角が立つ

I found this when I was reading kusamakura and I didn't understand it.

Comment: [角が立つ](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%A7%92%E3%81%8C%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A4)

Comment: Is は a typo? (I think it should be ば.)

Comment: oh sorry its ば, i writed it wrong and doens't realized it

Comment: It is a fairly famous line, you can find 'Japanese translations' on the web. https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%99%BA%E3%81%AB%E5%83%8D%E3%81%91%E3%81%B0%E8%A7%92%E3%81%8C%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A4%E6%83%85%E3%81%AB%E6%A3%B9%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%81%B0%E6%B5%81%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B-564882

Comment: You should supply the information of what (or why) you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

角【かど】が立つ【たつ】 is an idiom that means "may get on other's nerves (unintentionally)". The literal meaning is something like "to become angular/pointed". For example, 角が立たないような話し方をする means to speak politely and euphemistically avoiding any expressions that may make the listener upset.